# Checking if a viewcontroller exist, if not alloc/init (iOS)

Tags: iphone

I have a question about something I do often. Before making a new viewcontroller I check the instance variable named after the viewcontroller I want to present in some way.

```
if (self.viewcontroller == nil) {
   //alloc and init the viewcontroller, then set the reference to this.
}

//Else I use the instance variable reference without making a new object of it.
```

I do this on objects such as a viewcontroller with a single webview. The url the webview may open will be different, but this is set in the viewWillAppear method.

Is this bad practice? I also retains the "detailed" viewcontroller.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this, I usually write the getter method like this:

```
- (UIViewController*) viewController
    {
 if (!viewController)
        {
        viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    // ... any other setup that needs doing at this point.
        }
    return viewController;
    }
```

This allow me to use [self viewController] throughout my code, rather than check, alloc, init, retain throughout my code.

Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Using lazy initialization (as shown in your example) is a great idea, but the call to `-retain` is unnecessary, and leaks the view controller instance. Don't do that.

Comment: Yes, but I am unsure about the retaining. Why does it leak if I have in a property, which I release in dealloc in the "parent" viewcontroller.

Comment: @jlehr, thanks for spotting error. I have fixed it. alloc, along with new and copy, bestows ownership.

Comment: @Andreas, the extra retain (that I have now removed) would bring retainCount to 2. So, your subsequent release in dealloc would leave retainCount at 1. Sometimes it is helpful to use NSLog to show [obj retainCount] values.

Comment: By the way, Apple' docs suggest avoiding using `-retainCount`, or even thinking in terms of retain counts, because it can easily lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: True - what with autorelease pools and various 'hidden' retains. But with those caveats in mind, I still find it useful sometimes. With serious mismatched retain/release calls, I find NSZombieEnabled invaluable.